# HPCC ECL REGEX lookaround back-to-back values

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind, hpcc-ecl

I am using the REGEX Library as defined here http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

That being said I have a specific problem I would like to use regex to correct.

```
Input := '!Tim !~ Dan~'; 
Output := Tim !~ Dan

REGEXREPLACE('((?<![!])~)' ,Input,' '); //Results in : !Tim !~ Dan
REGEXREPLACE('((?![~])!)|((?<![!])~)',Input,' '); //Results in : Tim ~ Dan
```

What about this statement is causing the ! following the ~ to be removed?

How do I remove all ! and ~ without removing the combination of !~ in a single Regex command.

BONUS POINTS if you can tell me how to make !~! work in a single command.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following  regex:

```
(!~)|[!~]
```

and replace with `$1` backreference. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ5uA6/1).

**Details**:

- `(!~)` - matches *and captures into Group 1* a `!~` *sequence* of characters
- `|`  - or
- `[!~]` - a single `!` or `~` character

The `$1` backreference re-inserts the value stored in Group 1 back to the resulting string.

Comment: So this basically says Replace anything inside group 1 with itself and anything outside of the group with an empty string. I would have thought that $1 would have replaced each instance of the character set. Why is this not the case?

Comment: `$1` is a [*numbered backreference*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html). It refers to the text captured with the corresponding capturing group in the pattern. A [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is a pair of unescaped parentheses inside a pattern.

Comment: Okay, It is worth noting for others that (!~)|[!~] can not be referenced the other way around otherwise the characters from the set are replaced before the Group is found.